# Как изменить сам запрос или DDL, чтобы ускорить выборку по диапазону дат?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, оптимизация

MySQL 8.0.33. Имеется таблица (убрал незначащие поля в контексте вопроса):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `period` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `h_sum` double DEFAULT '0',
  `hw_sum` double DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `period` (`period`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

куда каждый месяц (поле `period` хранит дату = 1 число этого месяца) записываются несколько десятков тысяч записей. Сейчас в ней данные за 62 месяца, 2016426 записей. Один из запросов должен подсчитывать сумму `h_sum`+`hw_sum` за несколько месяцев (помесячно). Если так:

```sql
SELECT period, SUM(h_sum+hw_sum) paid
FROM data
WHERE period BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-07-01'
GROUP BY period
ORDER BY period;
```

запрос выполняется 19 сек! Его EXPLAIN:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | data | \N | index | period | period | 4 | \N | 1934197 | 33,18 | Using where |

Если переписать его с использованием оконных функций:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT period, SUM(h_sum+hw_sum) OVER (PARTITION BY period ORDER BY period) paid
FROM data
WHERE period BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-07-01'
```

то время выполнения уменьшается до 8 сек, но перестает использоваться индекс, EXPLAIN:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | data | \N | ALL | period | \N | \N | \N | 1934197 | 33,18 | Using where; Using filesort |

Если принудить использовать индекс:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT period, SUM(h_sum+hw_sum) OVER (PARTITION BY period ORDER BY period) paid
FROM data FORCE INDEX (period)
WHERE period BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-07-01'
```

то время уменьшается до 4 сек, но EXPLAIN (поле extra) становится совсем плохим:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | data | \N | range | period | period | 4 | \N | 641720 | 100,00 | Using index condition; Using MRR; Using filesort |

Вопрос: можно ли еще как-то оптимизировать/изменить запрос для ускорения времени выполнения (чем больше месяцев в выборке, тем дольше считается)? Может изменить тип поля? На что? Индекс? Структуру таблицы? Еще что-то?

Доп. вопрос: так ли нужен `ORDER BY period`, если данные записываются всегда последовательно по месяцам (т.е., к примеру, данные января 2023 не могут быть записаны ранее декабря 2022)? Если убрать его из запросов, то ничего не меняется: ни порядок месяцев в выборке, ни скорость выполнения...

Comment: *но EXPLAIN (поле extra) становится совсем плохим* Тебя интересует скорость работы или красота плана? *можно ли еще как-то оптимизировать* Да элементарно, Ватсон... Заводишь ещё одну таблицу, куда по завершении месяца считаешь и записываешь суммы за этот месяц. И когда нужна статистика, не полощешь всю таблицу, а берёшь предрасчётные данные. Если иногда нужна и статистика за неполный текущий месяц - значит, пересчитываешь сумму после каждого пополнения, ежедневно. *так ли нужен ORDER BY period* Да, без него сервер имеет право в любой момент изменить порядок возврата записей. И не предупредит..

Comment: @Akina спасибо, очень не хватало твоих советов после кончины sql.ru )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Селективность обычного индекса period

Индекс в запросе не особенно помогает, так как 641720 строк - это треть всех данных таблицы (EXPLAIN: 641720/2016426 ~ 1/3. Или колонка `filtered` 33,18 - там где с индексом). То есть селективность 1/3 - маленькая.

Для получения значений `h_sum` и `hw_sum` все равно берутся данные собственно из файла данных, а не из файла индекса - то есть происходит дополнительное чтение с диска.

Оптимизатор думает:

1. прочитать малоселективный индекс, а затем по ссылкам из него дополнительно прочитать `h_sum` + `hw_sum` из файла данных

или

2. прочитать только файл данных, по ходу фильтруя данные

И выбирает второй вариант. И не особенно ошибается со своим выбором - разница всего 19/8 ~ 2 раза. Обычно индексы работают многократно быстрее.

Как можно улучшить? Сделать покрывающий индекс или делать предварительные расчеты. Поправить тип period.

### Покрывающий индекс

Можете сделать один индекс сразу по нескольким полям: `period`, `h_sum`, `hw_sum` - он станет покрывающим в данном конкретном запросе. Порядок полей важен. Тогда будет использоваться исключительно индекс.

Мне трудно сказать, насколько это увеличит скорость, так как все равно много данных. А должно стать быстрее банально из-за того, что индекс компактнее чем все данные.

Попробую посчитать.

Получение данных из покрывающего индекса. Допустим 2016426 записей. Размер одной записи: `date` + 2 * `double` + `PK`. Я не стал искать точные размеры, думаю в 100 байт укладывается. Получилось 192 Мб. Чтение с диска займет доли секунды.

Также БД придется сделать суммирование 641720 * 2 = 1283440 раз. Если одна операция сложения double это 1-3 такта, то на 2 ГГц процессоре потратится 1283440÷2000000000 = 0,0006 сек. CPU делает и другие операции типа записи в кеш L1, я их не стал тут учитывать. Если я правильно рассчитываю, этим временем вообще можно пренебречь.

В итоге покрывающий индекс должен существенно помочь. Но это не точно.

### Предварительная агрегация

OLTP - обработка транзакций в реальном времени. Типичный веб-сайт, где важно время отклика.
OLAP - аналитика. Она всегда долгая из-за агрегации.

Хотите OLAP в реальном времени? Делайте предварительные расчеты и используйте простой SELECT по результатам.

Варианты:

- Сделать агрегацию средствами своего языка программирования и хранить в отдельной таблице. Или вообще в Redis кешировать.
- Настроить триггеры: при любой вставке/обновлении/удалении данных в таблицу `data` сама БД будет триггериться и обновлять таблицу аналитики типа `data_by_period`.

### NOT NULL

`period date DEFAULT NULL` - я везде читал, что NOT NULL быстрее. Но разница может быть ничтожная. Пробуйте.

Comment: *Настроить триггеры* Возможны две реализации - и обе плохие. Первая реализация - просто добавлять к текущей сумме вставляемое значение. Проблема - любой сбой, и в таблице неверная сумма, причём хрен определишь, что она сбойнула. Вторая реализация - при каждой вставке заново пересчитывать всю сумму. При этом опасность из первой реализации не грозит, но вставка замедлится более чем капитально.

Comment: *Сделать агрегацию средствами своего языка программирования* Зачем? тащить всё на клиента, считать, потом тащить обратно... сервер прекрасно это проделает и сам - по событию смены месяца. Причём можно задействовать как встроенный шедулер, так и триггер по условию, что месяц вставляемой записи больше месяца последней записи в таблице. В последнем случае вставка тормознёт, как описано в комменте выше - но только на самой первой записи месяца, а не на каждой.

Comment: да, почитал про NOT NULL, есть такие советы, альтернул столбец. Время выполнения запросов 1-го поста изменилось так: 19-->26,8-->15,4-->7  После ALTER делал OPTIMIZE/ANALYZE. Более того, с обратным изменением на DEFAULT NULL время осталось примерно тем же... Т.е. теперь стало еще хуже... Что я упустил?

Comment: *везде читал, что NOT NULL быстрее* Да. Для nullable полей MySQL вводит в структуру дополнительный байт для каждого поля. Впрочем, это редко приводит к тому, что в страницу файла помещается меньше записей. *разница может быть ничтожная* На самом деле не всегда. Проверка null-байта на null - это отдельная и дополнительная проверка. И тут как фишка ляжет - может не детектироваться, а может и в полтора раза замедлить. Первое, впрочем, чаще.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо за комменты. Меня учили, что триггеры - это хорошо. Где можно посмотреть информацию по проблеме "любой сбой, и в таблице неверная сумма". `тащить всё на клиента, считать, потом тащить обратно` - потому что если брать взрослую разработку - так лучше. Причины: 1. это легко засунуть в тесты TDD. 2. Не знаю, но скорее всего будут проблемы если несколько реплик, которые могут переключать мастера. И по всем репликам надо накатывать миграции. И сделать это через пипелины, в не вручную. В виде кода это существенно проще. А если использовать редис - то и не надо.

Comment: 3. БД может поменяться, а не все БД поддерживают TSQL единообразно. Поэтому поменять БД Mysql => Postgre будет проблематично. Хорошо, если только одна хранимка/шедулер/триггер. А если их тысячи? Проблема растет как снежный ком. Джо Селко советует вообще не использовать TSQL по причине - нет единообразия

Comment: @LuFang `Более того, с обратным изменением на DEFAULT NULL`. Может быть несколько причин. Может не прогрелись кеши разных уровней. Проверьте несколько раз. Может у вас SSD забился - эти диски работают быстрее когда в ячейку пишется по одному биту. А когда идет забивка более 1/2 диска - два бита и так далее. Это влияет на скорость. Может одновременно какие-то другие задачи грузят диск

Comment: *1. это легко засунуть в тесты TDD.* Это говорит только о том, что Вы используете на всё про всё один инструмент. Есть микроскоп - им и картинки смотрим, и орехи колем, и гвозди забиваем... получается же, чо... Сервер БД - такой же инструмент обработки, а вы его, беднягу, совершенно не используете, низведя до уровня тупого хранилища. Ну и кто в том виноват? А ответ прост: *будут проблемы если несколько реплик, которые могут переключать мастера. И по всем репликам надо накатывать миграции* - среда разработки не умеет. Ну никто и не парится...

Comment: `низведя до уровня тупого хранилища`. Именно так. Может быть переезд на другую БД, и привет проблемы. У нас сейчас идет переход, и придется переделывать кучу TSQL. Поменяли схему БД => отвалились вьюхи => перестало работать резервное копирование. Просто кто-то забыл или не знал, что нужно поменять схему вьюх. Будь это в коде и покрыто дешевыми юнит-тестами - пипелина не дала бы пролить доработку, и таких проблем не было как таковых. Написать TDD тест, затем код и повесить его на шедулер приложения - технологично. Использовать для этого БД - красиво и здорово, но проблемы озвучены выше.

Comment: Если у вас выстроен процесс решения таких проблем - напишите, будет интересно узнать.

Comment: @Akina там не дополнительный байт для каждого nullable поля, а бит.  То есть байт на каждые 8 nullable полей.